# Appium Android - Cant find view on window heirarchy'

Tags: java, android, appium

‘I am writing a test automation script in Appium for Android Application,……….

I have a scenario where I need to access a view that is directly attached to the window (not attached to the activity). Apparently, By.id method tries to find views which are added to the activity’s view hierarchy, which makes sense. Is there a way through which I can access views added to the window directly?

Answer (score 0):

If this view yours, save link to rootView(fe layout) and use layout.findViewbyid().

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am not having problem with Android App, its with the Appium tool